# Mass Payment doesn't work over NVP API

Tags: paypal, paypal-nvp

I'm trying to make a pay out to my service's users. I'm using Node.js SDK and choose Mass Payments to make automatical pay outs, since looks like it's only possible choise for me (user presses "withdraw" button inside mobile application, application sends request to our server and then our server makes call to PayPal NVP API to transfer money from our paypal account to user's paypal account). I'm making requests through NVP API.

PayPal responses with this error:

```
{
    "TIMESTAMP": "2015-02-17T20:20:29Z",
    "CORRELATIONID": "5a949b0257755",
    "ACK": "Failure",
    "VERSION": "2.3",
    "BUILD": "15295733",
    "L_ERRORCODE0": "10329",
    "L_SHORTMESSAGE0": "User is blocked",
    "L_LONGMESSAGE0": "We're sorry, but your PayPal account isn't currently eligible to send mass payments. Please contact either PayPal Customer Service or your account manager.",
    "L_SEVERITYCODE0": "Error"
}
```

What are possible reasons for such error? Maybe I'm using not appropriate type of account for making mass payments? What kind of account should I have? Or maybe I'm just using not appropriate API for making pay outs?

**UPD** this error occures when I'm trying to use live paypal servers. On sandbox servers mass payment works completely fine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about a PayPal account

Comment: In other words, only PayPal can tell you why you're getting that error. This is isn't a problem with your API call itself

Comment: Please note that your live account needs to be eligible and enabled for Mass Payments - as previous posts have stated, please contact PayPal Customer Service